# How to convert a string to a float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series of strings that represent cost data. I am attempting to convert the strings to floats

`df['Line Total'].map(float)`

which results in

`ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 3,300.00`

3,300.00 is the value from the first row of data.

I ran `df['Line Total'].map(repr)` based on the suggestion from here [python ValueError: invalid literal for float()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943877/python-valueerror-invalid-literal-for-float) but I don't see any extra or unnecessary characters in my data:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You don't see extra characters? How about the comma? That can't be parsed with a number.

Comment: I didn't identify the comma as an extra character which is what the problem was. Seems obvious in hindsight but that is usually the case.

Comment: i agree though that the other question covers it. I spent quite a bit of time searching for an answer but the problem was not seeing that the comma was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This had me stuck for awhile but thanks to this [Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int) I was able to figure out that commas in the string were the problem.

I ran `df['Line Total'] = df['Line Total'].str.replace(',', '')` and that took care of the problem!